# systemd cant access to camera via opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, systemd

## my problem is with ***Opencv*** and ***Systemd***, together!

I have installed a new **Opencv** on **Ubuntu 16.0.4**
and I wrote a program to get camera stream and store some of frames.
it worked "without" issue.
***but not work through Systemd***. the systemd unit is active (dont fail) **but no frame store in destination folder.**

i step by step look for problem and i find that code hang on opening the camera stream. that is:
cap.open("MyIpCameraAddress")

- I try to run my code through a bash script instead of . but problem exist.
- I also find that when i run program through systemd the relative addresses not work (when i test for open a picture)

---

### my systemd unit file:

[Unit]
Description= abc
After=network.target
[Service]
ExecStart= /path/to/executable
Restart=always
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

---

also test a systemd unit like above but for run a .sh file

when i start my system unit , the destination folder (that expect store some frames) give a lock icon on it.
but when run my program directly through terminal dont have any **lock icon** on dest folder.

---

EDIT:
I tested with Opencv v3.4.3 and v4.0.1 but the result is the same.

Comment: Could you post a minimal version of your program? Without the program we would need to guess what operations systemd could interfere with.

Comment: I was test a very simple program and that hang on this code:
cap.open("IPadress");

Comment: and `cap` would be a `VideoCapture` object? The [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#ac4107fb146a762454a8a87715d9b7c96) states that you need to pass a proper URL instead of an IP address.

Comment: You could try attaching a debugger to the systemd-started process to see where exactly it hangs, or run it under `strace`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the soloution
the problem is the way I installed the opencv ( i used the opencv inside the openvino pakage)
i installed independent version of opencv and the problem was solved.

if any one encountered any same problem feel free to ask me